# How to validate a number with preceding zeros with regex

Tags: c#, regex

**I have the following rule:**

Don't allow numbers of any sequence with 4 or more 0s at the beginning.

**So this number:**

0000438967

will fail validation (4 zeros)

**But this number:**

0004389678 (3 zeros)

Will pass validation.

the reason for this question was I needed verification on whether I was doing it correctly as, when checking in online Regex validators, I was getting mixed verification results. I know it sounds like a simple question but verification from others is important.

thanks
Russ

Comment: And what is your question regarding your attempt at implementing a solution?

Comment: @ShellFish: No mention of look-ahead, not a dup.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to handle cases like `0`, `0123`, `1`, `000`. Your question is unclear as is.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Seems pretty clear to me. 0, 0123, 1, 000 are all valid as none of them have 4 or more zeroes at the beginning.

Comment: @KaitingChen: Look at the rest of the answers below. Some of them don't work for those cases. It's easier to downvote those answer with a clearer problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbelievable amount of trial & error answers on this question! The solution is as simple as this:

```
string number = "0000438967";
bool pass = Regex.IsMatch(number, @"^0{0,3}[1-9]\d*$");
```

This allows numbers of any length, as long as there is at least one non-zero digit. Replace the last asterisk by {n} or {m,n} to also check length.

Of course, you may want to construct a Regex instance for repeated use.

If you also need the numeric value, you can immediately parse it if `pass == true`:

```
int value = Int32.Parse(number);
```

Of course, depending on the maximum length you want to allow you might need an `Int64`... but anyway you must provide a maximum length in the regex or the `Parse` can cause an overflow.

Comment: Thanks Kay, Yes, I agree, lots of trial and error. Your answer works and you took the time to explain yourself.

Comment: @RuSs With trial and error I referred to the number of answers here in such a short time. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use regular expression, you can use a [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertion.

```
^(?!0000)\d+$
```

> Lookarounds are zero-width assertions. They don't consume any characters on the string. The point of zero-width is the validation to see if a regex can or cannot be matched looking ahead or looking back from the current position, without adding them to the overall match.

**Example:**

```
Regex.IsMatch("0438967",      @"^(?!0000)\d+$"); // True
Regex.IsMatch("004389678",    @"^(?!0000)\d+$"); // True
Regex.IsMatch("000438967",    @"^(?!0000)\d+$"); // True
Regex.IsMatch("00004389678",  @"^(?!0000)\d+$"); // False
Regex.IsMatch("00000438967",  @"^(?!0000)\d+$"); // False
Regex.IsMatch("000000438967", @"^(?!0000)\d+$"); // False
```

Answer (score 3):

Zero to three zeroes followed optionally by a nonzero number followed by any number of numbers:

```
0{0,3}([1-9][0-9]*)?
```

It should accept:

000

While rejecting any number with 4+ zeroes at the beginning.

Don't use a lookahead/behind for this as that triggers backtracking.

EDIT: if your matching function does not perform an exact match then you'll need to do:

```
^0{0,3}([1-9][0-9]*)?$
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this..

```
        string myString = "00011111";//Valid

        if (Regex.IsMatch(myString,  @"^[0-9]{3}[1-9]+$"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: OP stated `Don't allow numbers of any sequence with 4 or more 0s at the beginning.`

Comment: Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^[0]{4}[0-9]+$") if it matches then it is invalid.

Comment: Note that `0000` will pass your test.

Comment: @hwnd: It's your choice to remove your answer - if it is correct, you can leave it there regardless. As for voting - I'll leave it to your imagination, since it's supposed to be anonymous.

Comment: Please validate the answer now... It works fine...@nhahtdh thanks for correcting me..

Comment: @SivaSankarGorantla: If you change `\d+` to `\d*` in your previous answer, it would validate `123` or `12345`. Your current answer only validate anything starts with three 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you accept no zeros at all and at least one non-zero digit, here is your regex:

```
string str = "001";
bool passed = Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^0{0,3}[1-9]\d*$");
```

**Explanation**: Regex check for 0 to 3 '0's, then for one non-'0' digits and then for zero or more of any digits.

if "000" is acceptable, then negative look-ahead solution from @hwnd is more  elegant. I would just use `0{4}` instead of `0000`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Regex to find out the string is valid or not

```
!Regex.Match(str, @"^0000(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success
```

here is working sample [rextester](http://rextester.com/BXYCBO20788)

Comment: This will match 0000 from any position.